# How to use selectableButtonBackground on Anko?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

How do I use `selectableButtonBackground` attribute on a custom View that uses Anko's `apply()` method inside its constructor like the following structure?

```
class XPTO(context: Context) : CardView(context) {

    init {
         this.apply {
             // I'd like to invoke selectableButtonBackground here
         }
}
```

I've tried to do `context.obtainStyledAttributes(arrayOf(R.attr.selectableItemBackground).toIntArray()).getDrawable(0)` but with no success.

Answer (score 2):

I just created an extension function to get the resource ids for attributes.

```
val Context.selectableItemBackgroundResource: Int get() {
    return getResourceIdAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground)
}

fun Context.getResourceIdAttribute(@AttrRes attribute: Int) : Int {
    val typedValue = TypedValue()
    theme.resolveAttribute(attribute, typedValue, true)
    return typedValue.resourceId
}
```

This way you can also add more attributes if needed. Example to put it in anko:

```
frameLayout {
   textView {
      text = "Test"
      backgroundResource = selectableItemBackgroundResource
      isClickable = true
   }
}
```

Don't forget the isClickable, else you won't see anything when you're clicking the textView

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this with Anko:

```
val backgroundResource = attr(R.attr.selectableItemBackgroundBorderless).resourceId
```